# Insertion Sort using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hello I want to perform insertion sort using dynamic memory allocation.Here is my code and this code is giving me error that lvalue is required.Please help me.

```
int *cardSorter(int *arrayPointer,int size){
    int j,i,key;
    for(j=1;j<size;j++){
        key=*(arrayPointer+j);
        i=j-1;
        while(i>=0||*(arrayPointer+i)>key){
            *((arrayPointer+i)+1)=*(arrayPointer+i);
            i--;
        }
        //GIVING ERROR AT THIS LINE : lvalue requied
        *(arrayPointer+i)+1=key;
    }
    return arrayPointer;
}
```

Here ArrayPointer is pointing to that memory which I have allocated dynamically.

Comment: Heh - the indenting plus expressions without enough brackets so I have to think too hard about operator precedence:)

Comment: sorry I am new to stack overflow I dont know so much about how to post with proper indenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as stated in your comment,

```
//GIVING ERROR AT THIS LINE : lvalue requied
*(arrayPointer+i)+1=key;
```

It should be

```
*(arrayPointer+i+1) = key;
```

or, even easier to read,

```
arrayPointer[i+1] = key;
```

Comment: Ok it worked but when I am trying to print the sorted values it is priting some values and some garbage values or addresses.
Please tell how to print the values returned by the function

Comment: @JustinJames `while(i>=0||*(arrayPointer+i)>key){` so you may read out of allocated memory. It should be `&&`.

Comment: Oh..Thanks a lot.I put || by mistake.